# Satisfication with irrelevant things

Tags: neuroscience

I am not sure if this question is better suited CogSci.SE so please tell me.

My question is why are we satisfied when we get things that aren't useful in any important way? For example, relating to Stack exchange, why are we satisfied and happy when we get badges because badges don't increase reputation or help you get privileges in Stack Exchange. Similar with Winter Bash. Why are we happy when we get hats? They are just for decorations. Is there a biological explanation for this?

**What chemical leads to us getting that feeling of satisfaction?**

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, stack exchange reputation seems about as irrelevant as stack exchange badges…

Comment: @canadianer well not for me bcos for some of these questions, the topics are based of projects I am doing so I need reputation to do more with my question so I can get answers so I can finish my projects...

Comment: If the question is re-stated as "what is the neurotransmitter mediating the sense of reward" this question is acceptable (DA, as answered). As the question stands now it reads "what is the neurotransmitter mediating the sense of irrelevant rewards?". That doesn't make sense to me, as relevant and irrelevant rewards are highly subjective and opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dopamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine) is one of many neurotransmitters which modulate information passage between one brain area to another. Dopamine is thought to play important role in  pleasure, addiction,
and learning.Massive increase in the
amount of dopamine released in the brain during video game play, the releasing of dopamine
are in areas thought to control reward and learning.

---

[image]
[Reference](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pNWPfbZ2s0IC&pg=PA53&dq=dopamine%20and%20video%20games&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6fmQVNCtJNijugTY6oDoCQ&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

---

> Certain neural structures, called the [reward system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reward_system), are critically involved in mediating the effects of reinforcement. A reward is an appetitive stimulus given to a human or some other animal to alter its behavior. Rewards typically serve as reinforcers. A reinforcer is something that, when presented after a behavior, causes the probability of that behavior's occurrence to increase. Note that, just because something is labelled as a reward, it does not necessarily imply that it is a reinforcer. A reward can be defined as reinforcer only if its delivery increases the probability of a behavior.

The reason why we are happy when we get these decorative items is because they are things which we can possess. Reward system is responsible for this kind of behavior, when we gain or achieve something in life its usually gets rewarded in the form of a pleasure. Foraging ants and bees are provided with these reward systems and which in turn makes these animals to derive a pleasure out of their daily achievements. Whether in life, video game or stack exchange or anything, an achievement is something brain thinks relevant and rewards it with a pleasure in mind.

Considering badges in stack exchange, really badges are an analogy to reputation. When we have more badges usually our charisma increases like in the case of reputation. Also levels and scores in games,achievements in office, stack exchange badges and hats all fall under the same analogy. So when we have more badges we are meant to be more successful and brain will reward us to attain more badges and also people like hats too.

> References
>
> Digital Media: Transformations in Human Communication - Paul Messaris, Lee Humphreys
>
> Cyber Junkie: Escape the Gaming and Internet Trap - Kevin Roberts